# what is minimum version of jre to use java2word api

Tags: java, java2word

I am using API java2word-3.1.jar to create doc file.
 it is working good in JRE 1.5+ version. 
 but I want to use it in JRE1.4.

could you please tell me any solution.

currently getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: **word/api/interfaces/IDocument (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:539)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:123)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:55)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:187)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:289)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:274)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)**
```

thanks and regards
Shankar

Answer (score 1):

Either recompile the package yourself, if it will compile under 1.4, or else upgrade your Java to something that hasn't been unsupported since October 30th, 2008.

> what is minimum version of jre to use java2word api

I don't know why you're asking that, when you've already established conclusively that it's 1.5.

Comment: thanks for reply. But I can't upgrade java. I need any java API to create  doc file in jre1.4 only. I really appreciate for reply.

Comment: hi All, this problem has been solved by updating and compiling  existing source code for java2word in jre1.4 env. I'll be more happy to help if any one required it.

Comment: @Shaan In that case you should consider marking this answer as correct.